# Корутины, как получить InputStream из Flow<List<ByteArray>>?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, coroutine, flow

В общем получаю из Room `Flow<List<ByteArray>>`, вопрос как преобразовать его в `InputStream`?

```
class FlowListInputStream(
     private val scope: CoroutineScope, 
     private val flow: Flow<List<ByteArray>> //размер списка до нескольких тысяч
    ): InputStream() {

    override fun read(): Int {
       //todo...
    }
}
```

**Контекст:** у меня в SQLite в виде BLOB хранятся video/audio/image - местами довольно большие до гигабайт. Размер записи в районе 1 мб, соответственно я получаю SQL запросом список BLOB сформированных в виде массивов `ByteArray`, которые согласно последней моде возвращаются в виде [асинхронных Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html). Теперь для того, чтобы отобразить media, мне нужно преобразовать в `InputStream`, который уже можно засунуть в Glide или в MediaPlayer.

Comment: а что имеется в виду под "Размер записи в районе 1 мб? лист содержит один ресурс, побитый по 1 мб? И в flow будет только один лист?

Comment: Да, в `Flow` один `List`, в каждом элементе списка примерно по 1 мб

Comment: не очень понял смысл такого разбиения, если 1ГБ разбить на 1024 ByteArray и запихнуть их в лист, то этот лист всё равно будет в 1ГБ грубо говоря. Я с Blob не работал в андройде, но разве это не то, что нужно https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Blob? вместо flow, и там есть методы getBinaryStream, которые и возвращают InputStream

Comment: @IR42 вопрос был не об этом. Если вам легче пусть размеры чанков/кусков будет не по 1 мб, а по 1 гб, ок?

Answer (score 0):

Оно? Выглядит странно, возможно я чего-то не понял

```
class FlowListInputStream(
    private val flow: Flow<List<ByteArray>> //размер списка до нескольких тысяч
) : InputStream() {
    val s by lazy {
        val streams = runBlocking { flow.first() }.map { ByteArrayInputStream(it) }
        SequenceInputStream(Vector(streams).elements())
    }
    override fun read(): Int = s.read()
}
```

Comment: Очень похоже, но смущают 2 обстоятельства: 1) антипаттерн с использованием `runBlocking` 2) Не кажется, что это приведет к аллокации всего списка в памяти и потеряется последовательность аллокации по элементам списка?

Comment: @Barmaley 1) вы больше никак не сможете подружить синхронный InputStream с асинхронными клрутинами, кроме как через runBlocking. 2) не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду под последовательной аллокацией тут. Конечно будет весь список в памяти, ведь это List. А Flow - это всего лишь асинхронный холодный поток данных. Очень похожий на rx Observable, если так проще. Если вы получили объект в collect у Flow или в subscribe у Observable, то этот объект уже в памяти естественно

Comment: Поэтому и написал, что странно выглядит, мне кажется вам нужно что-то другое. Может быть `Flow<ByteArray>`, куда будет по надобности эмититься blob? Или что-то вроде пагинации